# AWS route53 removing resource set

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services

I'm using dnscurl.pl which is recommended through Amazon in order to remove record sets from route53. I'm running into an error that I can't figure out. Route53 is responding with error: InvalidInput. Message: Invalid XML ; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest'.

```
    <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-02-29/">
      <Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidInput</Code>
        <Message>Invalid XML ; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest'.</Message>
      </Error><RequestId>51c5c1de-c246-11e2-b977-934c36c18aa7</RequestId>        
    </ErrorResponse>
```

My request is as follows:

```
    dnscurl.pl --keyname my_key_name -- -s -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" -X POST --upload-file /tmp/tmp.qEYXdPVpFh https://route53.amazonaws.com/2012-02-29/hostedzone/xxxxxxxxxx/rrset
```

The xml file being used is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-12-12">
        <ChangeBatch>
          <Comment>Deleting Record for staging.mysite.com. at Tue May 21 17:37:52 UTC 2013</Comment>
          <Changes>
            <Change><Action>DELETE</Action><ResourceRecordSet><Name>staging.mysite.com.</Name><Type>A</Type><AliasTarget><HostedZoneId>xxxxxxxxxx</HostedZoneId><DNSName>awseb-e-s-awsebloa-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.</DNSName></AliasTarget></ResourceRecordSet></Change>

            <Change><Action>DELETE</Action><ResourceRecordSet><Name>ec2.staging.mysite.com.</Name><Type>CNAME</Type><TTL>300</TTL><ResourceRecords><ResourceRecord><Value>ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com</Value></ResourceRecord></ResourceRecords></ResourceRecordSet></Change>
    </Changes>
</ChangeBatch>
```

I can't find any information about why the XML is invalid. It checks through all XML validators. Any ideas of where to go with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-12-12">
```

to this:

```
<ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-12-12/">
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you don't close the:

```
</ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest>
```